# Getting all storage keys indexed by a smart contract - getStorageKeys or parity_listStorageKeys

Tags: ethers.js, storage, get-storage-at

I've seen that the functions `getStorageKeys` or `parity_listStorageKeys` have been discontinued from the most popular clients. Thus, the developer only has access to `getStorageAt` (I'm using `etheres.js`. Is there a way to automatically get all the keys that index values from a specific smart contract?
A possibility is to know a-priori which values are define and use `getStorageAt`. However, for dynamic-sized types, this would include to use `getStorageAt` in a loop until only zeroes are retrieved, and this doesn't look very efficient.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For this reason, to the https://github.com/0xweb-org/0xweb library, I've added the TypeScript code generation for the contract's storage reader. It works only if the source code is available, e.g. the contract is validated.

```bash
npm i 0xweb -g
0xweb init
0xweb install 0x1234... --name FooContract --chain eth
```

It generates the contract's client class to call read/write methods, but it has also the `storage` field, which contains getters for all the storage variables. It works also with structs and dynamic content like arrays and mappings.

```
contract FooContract {
  uint256 a;
  string b;
  struct Foo {
     uint256 c;
     uint256 d;
  }
  Foo foo;
  address[] list;
  mapping(uint256 => address) people;
}
```

```typescript
import { FooContract } from '@0xweb/eth/FooContract/FooContract'
import { Config } from '@dequanto/Config'

let contract = new FooContract();
let aValue = await contract.storage.a();
let bValue = await contract.storage.b();
// from struct
let cValue = await contract.storage.foo('c');
// or the first item of the array
let arrItem = await contract.storage.list(0);
// mapping
let mappingValue = await contract.storage.people(100n);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with ethers.js / without using additional third-party libraries?

Comment: With `ethers.js`  you can just call the `getStorageAt` to read some specific slots data. But the locations and the type handling you have to do manually.